# Guess the first revision to merge when merging up to a revision

Tags: svn, merge

I need to automate merging changes up to a specific revision from trunk to a release branch. When you merge up to the head of trunk SVN automatically detects the first revision r2417 :

```
$ svn merge "^/trunk"
--- Merging r2417 through r2526 into '.':
...
 U   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r2417 through r2526 into '.':
 U   .
```

However, if I need to merge up to r2523 I'm forced to specify the first revision as well otherwise the syntax of the command is incorrect.

```
$ svn merge -r :2523 "^/trunk"
svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument ':2523'

$ svn merge -r 2523 "^/trunk"
svn: E205001: Try 'svn help merge' for more information
svn: E205001: Second revision required

svn merge -r 2416:2523 "^/trunk"
--- Merging r2418 through r2523 into '.':
...
 U   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r2418 through r2523 into '.':
 U   .
```

How to determine the first revision SVN would use and put it in my script?

Comment: Doesn't you last example already contain the solution? You should be able to pick an arbitrarily early revision (like, say: 1) and `svn:mergeinfo` will prevent double merges. So `svn merge 1:2523 ^/trunk` *should* work. Unfortunately, I cannot try from where I am and I don't want to post a wrong answer.

Comment: thanks for testing for me. I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a very early revision to start the merge from and rely on Subversion to prevent double-merges. Since subversion counts revisions from 1, that would obviously be early enough.

Subversion tracks what has already been merged in its `svn:mergeinfo` property and will not attempt to merge these revisions again. As long as:

- `svn:mergeinfo` is correct and up to date and
- no options to explicitly disregard it (like `--ignore-ancestry`) are given,

it's safe to merge using:

```
svn merge 1:2523 ^/trunk
```

Also see the [chapter on merging in the Red Bean Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).

In fact, Subversion preventing a double-merge can be seen in the last example of the question:

```
svn merge -r 2416:2523 "^/trunk"            <-- merge from 2416
--- Merging r2418 through r2523 into '.':   <-- starts from 2418, not 2416
```

For the sake of completeness, it is also possible to read the latest merged revision from `svn:mergeinfo` and start from the next one. Subversion will take care of it anyway so there should be no need for doing it this way.